# Find the form of $f$

Tags: calculus

For $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ , the following holds:

1. $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R} : f(x+y) = f(x)\cdot f(y)$
2. $\forall y : \lim_{x\to y}f(x) = f(y)$
3. $f$ is not identically $0$

Find the form of the function (rational/exponential/logarithmic/other...).
I was thinking this: if $f(x) = y$ for every $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, then $f(x+y) = y\cdot y$ always and also $$\lim_{x\to y}f(x) = \lim_{x\to y}y = y = f(y)$$
So is it correct to say that the form of $f$ is rational?

Comment: If $f(x)=y$ then how is $f(x+y)=y\cdot y$?

Comment: possible duplicate http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/727958/showing-the-exponential-and-logarithmic-functions-are-unique-in-satisfying-their

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, saying "the form of $f$ is rational" is not correct.

Consider these facts:

$$f(0)=f(0+0)=f(0)\cdot f(0)=[f(0)]^2$$

This means $f(0)=0$ or $f(0)=1$. If $f(0)=0$ then

$$f(x)=f(x+0)=f(x)\cdot f(0)=f(x)\cdot0=0$$

which is given to be not true. So $f(0)=1$.

Now let $f(1)=a$. Then we get

$$f(2)=f(1+1)=f(1)\cdot f(1)=a^2$$
$$f(3)=f(2+1)=f(2)\cdot f(1)=a^3$$
$$f(4)=f(3+1)=f(3)\cdot f(1)=a^4$$

and so on. We clearly see that $f(n)=a^n$ for non-negative integers $n$.

We also get

$$f(1)=f\left(\frac 12+\frac 12\right)=f\left(\frac 12\right)\cdot f\left(\frac 12\right)=\left[f\left(\frac 12\right)\right]^2$$

So $f\left(\frac 12\right)=\pm\sqrt a=\pm a^{1/2}$. With more investigation you see that the sign there must be positive, so $f(x)=a^x$ also holds for $x=\frac 12$.

And so on. I think you can continue from here.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $e^{x+y}=e^x\cdot e^y$ continuous in $\mathbb R$.